# Persisting User between Web App and IOS App

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, devise, turbolinks

I have an app for both desktop and uses turbolinks wrapper for IOS and ANDROID.  I don't have any issue on ANDROID.  But on IOS, if the user logs out of the desktop app, User has to log back in when he/she goes to my iphone app icon (see full steps below).

My questions are:
 - what is causing this? (strange not an issue with ANDROID)
 - what/Where do i need to fix this. 
 - is this a rails side issue, turoblinks issue or 
 - below is code from Rails side. NB: I don't have the IOS app code -(using a mobile programmer to help me)

I have an app that uses-
1- Ruby on Rails gem "rails", "5.2.2"
2- GEM - Devise
gem "devise", ">= 4.2.0"
gem "devise-async"
3- Turbolinks wrapper for native Android/IOS - 
4- Postgres

Here's the scenario:

- User is logged in on desktop (IE/EDGE)
- User logs into IOS App and uses it. swipes closed.  clicks on icon.
  logs back in fine.
- User swipes App closed
- User logs out of desktop App
- User clicks on APP ICON on IOS - it requires them to sign in again. 
  (This is not an issue on the ANDROID

User model

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token_is_present
```

265

```
    before_save :set_name
  266  
  ...
 1413    end
 1414  
 1415:   def ensure_authentication_token_is_present
 1416:     if authentication_token.blank?
 1417:       self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
 1418      end
 1419    end
 1420  
 1421:   def generate_authentication_token
 1422      loop do
 1423        token = Devise.friendly_token
 1424:       break token unless User.find_by(authentication_token: token)
 1425      end
 1426    end
```

SESSIONS CONTROLLER:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::BaseController



skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user_using_x_auth_token

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token,   only: :destroy
  before_action      :authenticate_user_by_token!, only: :destroy

  def create

        user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user] && 

params[:user][:

email])
        if invalid_password?(user)
          respond_with_error("Incorrect email or password", 401)
        else
          render(
            json: { auth_token: user.authentication_token },
            location: root_path,
            status: :created
          )
        end
      end

  def destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)

    head :ok
  end

  private

  def invalid_password?(user)
    user.blank? || !user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
  end

end
```

authentication methods

```
def authenticate_user_using_x_auth_token
user_email = params[:id].presence
auth_token = request.headers["X-Auth-Token"].presence

user = user_email && User.find_by(email: user_email)

if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, auth_token)
  sign_in user, store: false
else
  respond_with_error(
    "Could not authenticate with the provided credentials",
    401
  )
end
```

end

```
def authenticate_user_by_token!
    auth_token = request.headers["X-Auth-Token"].presence
    user       = User.find_by(authentication_token: auth_token)

    if user.present?
      sign_in user, store: false
    else
      respond_with_error("Could not authenticate with the provided credentials", 401)
    end
  end
```

Comment: so i saw this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924606/ios-rails-devise-how-to-persist-user-login-session-vs-authentication-token

This is in DEVISE... and we are not using.
  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session cookies are cleared out on a Turbolinks-iOS app each time the app closes. You are probably using a persistent cookie, and when you log out, if devise is clearing out `user.remember_created_at`, then the cookie is invalidated.

Try adding this to the devise configuration:

```
config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = false
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/11026007206226c1189f6050ab05d2284f47a669/lib/devise.rb#L130-L132